# Proof concern about $f'(x)=lim_{n\to\infty }f_n'(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

$1)$Functions $f_n$ are differentiable on interval $X$.

$2)$Exists $a\in X$ st $f_n(a)$ sequence is convergent.

$3)$ $f_n'(x)$($\frac{df_n}{dx}$) sequence is uniformly convergent on interval $X$.

Then

$1)$ **Sequence $f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent on any $E\subset X$ bounded set(converges to $f(x)$)**

$2)$ **$f$ is differentiable on $X$ and $f'(x)=lim_{n\to\infty }f_n'(x)$**

Proof of the book starts with this.

First let's proof that for any $x\in X$ $$g_n(x)=\frac{f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$

sequence is uniformly convergent on $X$ \ ${x_0}$ set.

Isn't $g_n(x)$ same as $f_n'(x_0)$ for which we already have uniform convergence why we  need to prove? Can you help to figure out this part.

Comment: No.  Think of $g_n$ as a function with a removable discontinuity at the point $x=x_0$.  It is not defined at that point but the value $f_n'(x_0)$ could be assigned there and would make it continuous.

Comment: Is it also given that the derivative $f'_n$ is continuous? Otherwise, in general, we cannot recover $f_n$ from its derivative $f'_n$ (i.e., $f_n(x)-f_n(a) = \int_a^x f'_n(t)dt$) and the remaining tool is probably mean-value theorem.

Comment: The usual version of this theorem does not require the derivatives $f_n'$ to be continuous.   (You *can* recover a function from a discontinuous derivative, but I won't say how.)  There is a proof of the theorem in *Section 9.6.1 Limits of Discontinuous Derivatives* in this textbook: https://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/TBB-AllChapters-Landscape.pdf    The mean-value theorem does play a role.